# Templates with Operation for 2d array addition

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, operator-overloading

I have two 2d arrays `arr1` this belongs to object `s1` and `arr2` this belongs to object `s2` and I want to store the addition to the object `s3`. After a lot of searching and experimenting with `this` , this is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    class Matrix
    {
       private:
         T arr[2][2];
         T temp_arr[2][2];

       public:
         Matrix();
         void display();
         void seter(T _var[2][2]);

         Matrix operator + (Matrix tmp)
         {
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
               for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
                  this->temp_arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+tmp.arr[i][j];

            return *this;
         }
    };

    template<class T>
    Matrix<T>::Matrix()
    {
    }


    template<class T>
    void Matrix<T>::display()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            cout<<endl<<arr[i][j];
    }

    template<class T>
    void Matrix<T>::seter(T _var[2][2])
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
                arr[i][j]=_var[i][j];
    }

    int main()
    {
     double arr1[2][2];
     double arr2[2][2];

     double x=2.5,y=3.5;

     for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            arr1[i][j]=x++;

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            arr2[i][j]=y++;

    Matrix<double> s1;
    Matrix<double> s2;
    Matrix<double> s3;

    s1.seter(arr1);
    s2.seter(arr2);

    s3=s1+s2;

    s1.display();
    cout<<endl;
    s2.display();
    cout<<endl;
    s3.display();

    return 0;
 }
```

It still returns the array of the object `s1`, I can't figure why since many examples on the web have something similar to my code.

Comment: `Matrix operator + (Matrix tmp)`  Operator `+` should be returning a brand new `Matrix`, not the existing Matrix.  Returning the existing Matrix would be the job of `operator +=`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't see what the rule of three has to do with this.

Comment: @juanchopanza I retracted it.  Saw X when problem was Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue, you should

1. Remove the `temp_arr` from your `Matrix` class and `operator +`.
2. Change this line in `operator +` from this:`this->temp_arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+tmp.arr[i][j];` to this: `arr[i][j] += tmp.arr[i][j];`

There is no need for `temp_arr` in your implementation.

Here is a live example using the changes above:  http://ideone.com/lMF3kT

---

The other issue is that you are changing the original `Matrix` object when calling `operator +`.  This is counter-intuitive, since `+` should not change the original object, instead a new object should be returned.

To address this issue, you can move the code (once fixed) out of `operator +` and move it to `operator +=`.

```
Matrix& operator += (const Matrix& tmp)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            arr[i][j] += tmp.arr[i][j];
    return *this;
}
```

Note that we return the original object as a reference.  Now, we can implement `operator +` in terms of `operator +=`:

```
Matrix operator + (const Matrix& tmp)
{
    Matrix temp(*this);
    return temp += tmp;
}
```

Edit:

Made parameters const references.

Comment: Isn't that `operator +=` ?

Comment: I tried that, but I don't want the array of `s1` object to change. After the changes it works exactly as I want!

Comment: There are two issues, the first being the calculation just being wrong, and that the operators are awry.  The answer fixes both.

Comment: Operators that don't change data members are generally made const

Answer (score 1):

You should not have `temp_arr` as a class member, instead use a temporary instance in your const operators and return it on the stack

Also, since people should be able to add `const` instances, make your `operator +` a `const` member function:

```
Matrix operator + (const Matrix& tmp) const
{
    Matrix ret(*this);
    ret+=tmp;
    return ret;
}
```

The above should help illustrate the difference between + and += but you may be able to optimize it.

Comment: I tried this first and then I''ve thought `this` should fix my issue because I had hard time returning the `temp_arr`. I've tried adding `Matrix(T _temp[2][2]);` to pass the new array but it doesn't work.

Comment: No actually, but I am trying to make it work. You are creating `ret` and you are adding with `tmp` , but I want to add `tmp` with `arr`.  And also I don't have an opeartor `+=` , do I have to make one?

Comment: You cannot change data members in that array. You should implement both as practice to see the difference, but if you want you can just change it to the same looping setting the member array as you go

Comment: I am upvoting this answer also because it's the part of the solution. I didn't get that I needed another operator.